# Why is 2-3 volts on 120 v circuit that is not connected

Tags: electrical

I see 2-3 volts on a 120 volt [image]circuit that is not connected to a breaker.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnected  wires are a radio antenna. They pick up all sorts of junk which high impedance DVMs can see because they are so sensitive.   Mind you, on AC mode your meter doesn't *only* look for 60Hz, though crosstalk between parallel wires is a common source.

Plug an incandescent night light into the circuit.  I bet the phantom voltage instantly goes away, and the night light does not light.

Answer (score 0):

Digital voltmeters are highly sensitive and some can detect micro-amps of current. We call this a phantom current and basically ignore it.  It could be static or some sort of induction. I would ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

These measured voltages are sometimes called phantom voltages. If it were a "real" 2.2 V between the wire and ground, then if you would put your meter into current mode, it would show a significant current, but I would bet it will not.